# Python - MySQLdb: ValueError - unsupported format - although the use of the execute substitution

Tags: python, mysql, string-formatting, mysql-python

I'm trying to UPDATE some BLOB images in a database with the python-mysqldb package but i always get this error:

```
ValueError: unsupported format character ',' (0x2c) at index 64
```

I've successfully added the images some time ago with the execute substitution tools for example like this:

Set up connection to db:

```
db  = MySQLdb.connect( host="127.0.0.1", port=0815, user="javert", passwd="ureyes", db="some_db") 
cur = db.cursor()
```

read image files:

```
images = [ open( image_file, 'rb') for image_file in folder ]
image1, ..., image6 = images
```

insert images:

```
command = """INSERT INTO database_table (column1, ..., column6) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"""
cur.execute( command, args=( image1, ..., image6))
db.commit()
```

Now I've replaced the insert command with the following and get the described error:

```
"""UPDATE database_table SET column1=%s, column2=%s, column3=%s, column4=s%, column5=%s, column6=%s WHERE id=table_row_id"""
```

Thank You for your help!

Comment: Why don't you use `pyodbc`?

Comment: @SomethingSomething: I didn't know about this module. Could you describe the advantages of it compared to mysqldb? Why should i use it?

Comment: `pyodbc` is compatible with more libraries and does not need mysql dlls for its installation. I now noticed that mysql-python was updated more recently, so I don't know what's better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`column4=s%,` should be `column4=%s,` (note the inverted `,` and `s`).

Observe that this is what the error message says (`,` isn't an appropriate "format character"): the "format character" is what comes after the `%`, and `,` is not a valid one.

Comment: Problem solved. Now everything runs like charm. Thank you very much for your help and also for the description of the error. I promise i will check that first next time! '

Comment: @ChristianKaiser Don't worry — I didn't mean to imply you *should* have known, you need to learn about that error one day before you can recognize it : )

Comment: I resent because i should have take a look into it but i ways so busy trying to find a mysqldb related format problem because i took my some trial and error to get the execute logic work with blobs. So thanks again for pointing it out and have a nice Christmas with your family.